# key value routing in Zend Framework Route

Tags: php, zend-framework, router, routes, hostname

I'm using a Hostname route to capture a subdomain and use as a category. I then chain a Router route for the controller, action and key/value pairs.

```
$hostnameRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
 ':customer.ddc.:domain',
 array(
  'customer' => ':customer'
 )
);

$routerRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
 ':controller/:action/*',
 array(
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'index'
)
);
$chainedRoute = $hostnameRoute->chain($routerRoute);
$frontController->getRouter()->addRoute('default',$chainedRoute);
```

I can capture everything except the key/value pairs on the URI. Adding them causes the Params object in the Request to not get populated.

This works:  http://category.mydomain.com/controller/action/

This does not: http://category.mydomain.com/controller/action/username/frank

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a bug which prevents wildcard matching when chaining routes. The comments in the bug description were very helpful in solving this issue with just a few lines of code change.

framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6654

Answer (score 1):

Try to use without `/*`.

```
$routerRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':controller/:action',
    array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index'
    )
);
```

as in [12.5.2. Using a Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) is described.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Removing the * did not help. 12.5.7. Route Types discusses adding the * to match trailing key/value pairs in the URI. However, it appears it's only capturing a single key. Any attempt to add more, and the Params in the request object do not get populated at all.

Comment: It is a bid weird. Right now `http://category.mydomain.com/controller/action/username/frank` is redirecting you to which `controller`, `action`, etc ?

Comment: It doesn't redirect anywhere. The mappings for the routes are completely gone. I think I've hunted this down as a bug in ZF:
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6654

Answer (score 1):

The suggested patch didn't work for me.  I adapted another patch found elsewhere on the ZF website and it seems to work well: http://pastie.org/1815135